# Conditional expectation equality

Tags: stochastic-processes

Does this statement hold and how to prove it correctly?
$$
\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathbb{F})^2) = \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathbb{F}))
$$

Any help? Thanks.

$\mathbb{F}$ is a sigma algebra. $X$ may or **may not** be $\mathbb{F}$-measurable.

Comment: Did you intend the left-hand side to be $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid\mathbb{F})^2)$ or what you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
Use that
$$
\mathbb{E}(Z)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(Z\mid\mathbb{F}))
$$
with $Z=X\mathbb{E}(X\mid\mathbb{F})$.

Comment: That makes one side ${\mathbb E}(({\mathbb E}(X|{\mathbb F})^2)$, which is not the same as
$({\mathbb E}({\mathbb E}(X|{\mathbb F}))^2$.  It's not clear which one was intended in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove that if $X\in\mathbb L^2$, then 
$$\mathbb E[(\mathbb E(X\mid \mathcal F))^2]=\mathbb E(X\cdot\mathbb E(X\mid \mathcal F)).$$

Using the definition of conditional expectation, we have for each $\mathcal F$-measurable random variable $Y$ that 
$$\mathbb E(XY)=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(X\mid\mathcal F)Y).$$
Indeed, this is true if $Y=\chi_F$ for some $F\in\mathcal F$ and this can be extended by an approximation argument.